# Datetime picker with 12 hours format - Umbraco admin panel

Tags: datetimepicker, umbraco7

I need datetime picker in 12 hour format in Umbraco admin panel,  the default datetime picker uses 24 hours format as displayed below:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any way i can modify the Default Date time picker to use 12 hours format with AM and PM options? Or is there any package available for the same? I have checked on the Date Range Picker but it is for picking up date time range. I need to pick one date only.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible:

[image]

You need to change the picker's configuration. Go to the Date Picker's settings and set the **Date format** property to YYYY-MM-DD **hh**:mm:ss (instead of the default YYYY-MM-DD **HH**:mm:ss):

[image]